# I achieved great results - or some great results?

Tags: determiners

> For the last 2 year I've been using the method I described to you, and I achieved (**some**) great results.

Would such sentence look better with or without the determiner **some**?

What would be the difference in meaning or tone, if any?

I remember that omitting **some** can change the meaning in some situations, like in

> I bought (some) books! (telling to his wife upon entering the apartment)

Would imply, with **some** omitted, "I bought not some other thing(s), but books".

Comment: In an interview, for example, or even a report, I would omit the *some.* Interviews are not a time to be modest. Although the best way would be to quantify the results in a specific statement: I increased sales by 15% over the previous quarter's results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I achieved some great results." means that you had a number of results that were amazing among all of the results, but maybe not all of the results were amazing. I don't think it has a negative connotation, particularly if you're talking about something that has a lot of variability beyond your control, like for example, training aggressive dogs to make them less dangerous.

"I achieved great results." has the sense of "I used this tool in the circumstances that called for it, and it consistently did well."

In general, when we say "some X" instead of just "X", we are qualifying our statement to mean "maybe not every X/all of X". That's not *always* true though. For example, "My husband brought me {some} flowers." The "some" is optional and its inclusion has little effect on the meaning of the sentence. On the other hand, if I omit "some" from "I think {some} people like being angry." I change the inferred meaning to "I think (all people in general) like being angry."

Comment: Oh, so the addition of **some** qualifies the statement a bit, implying that some results might have been not so great.

Comment: @CopperKettle That's how I interpret it, although I think some speakers use qualifiers like "some" to adjust the tone to seem less boastful or to make the statement less absolute instead of using them to be more precise. For example, "I _never_ leave home without a towel." versus "I _usually_ carry a towel with me."

Answer (score 3):

I would say the use of the word "some" diminishes the impact of the words that follow it. "I achieved some great results" would maybe infer less "great results" than "I achieved great results". Moreso in the book example.

Answer (score 0):

I recall Bobby Fischer mentioning in his notes to a chess game that "we had some great results with this system." Meaning, that in a number of discrete cases, employing the system had had a great result. If he had said "we had great results with this system" this would have a more general sense. Of course, the meaning is the same whether you use *some* or not: the "results" in question are the outcomes of chess games, whether referenced discretely or *en masse.*